# Magento redirect concern

Tags: redirect, geoip

I am from India and we have a website based on magento. It has two stores one for world and one for india. Both are like this respectively : http://mysite.com and http://mysite.com/in .

My concern is what will happen if i detect the user geoip and accordingly redirect the indian visitor to the indian site. Will i be able to visit the admin section or it will also be redirected with an **/in** at the end.

Comment: How are you making the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess to redirect everyone Except Your IP.